# How can I keep some values while deleting waste text?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to delete all text, except ns**.ts values. How can I do this?

I already tried to use remove and replace methods, but it was not successful.

```py
import urllib.request
basic_playlist = 'http://intek-m.ru/live/novomyt_komar/s.m3u8'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(basic_playlist).read()
format_response = str(response)
last = format_response[2:-3]
print(last)
```

Current output:

```
#EXTM3U\n#EXT-X-VERSION:3\n#EXT-X-ALLOW-CACHE:NO\n#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:4\n#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:54288\n#EXTINF:4.266667,\ns54288.ts\n#EXTINF:2.133333,\ns54289.ts\n#EXTINF:4.266667,\ns54290.ts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), in your case `re.findall(r'ns\d+\.ts', last)` should do the job. Assuming there are only numbers in your pattern ns**.ts

Comment: Hey makonzaki. Thanks for your solution. It works! Current output: ['ns88353.ts', 'ns88354.ts', 'ns88355.ts']